# Bash KSH Script Removing Last N Char

Tags: regex, bash, ksh

I am trying to do remove last 15 character from a string and I have to run that BASH script with "ksh". It works with "bash" very well, but with "ksh" it does not. Here is my code,

```
#!/bin/bash
ggate_location="'$(ps -ef|grep mgr)'"
for word in $ggate_location
do
[[ $word =~ mgr\.prm$ ]] && echo ${word::-15}
done
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is the output of `$(ps -ef | grep mgr)`

```
ggate 53158 1 1 Sep04 ? 1-14:53:02 ./mgr PARAMFILE /gecici/GoldenGate/ggs12c/dirprm/mgr.prm REPORTFILE /gecici/GoldenGate/ggs12c/dirrpt/MGR.rpt PRO 
ggate 143867 32840 0 16:07 pts/5 00:00:00 grep --color=auto mgr
```

Comment: KSH probably does not support `=~`. Did you check with `man ksh`?

Comment: I'm sure your script could be simplified a lot while made portable, care to share the output of your `ps -ef|grep mgr` ?

Comment: No, it does support. Because instead of trimming the word, I have used printing the word and it worked. So it isn't the case.

Comment: Why do you want to use the script with `ksh` and why do you think it makes a difference at all? Running a Bash script from `ksh` should work fine, just like you can run Python scripts from any shell, for example.

Comment: Drop the quotes in the definition of `ggate_location`. If the output of the pipeline is `a b c`, then `ggate_location` has the *literal* value `'a b c'`, and `word` will take the values `'a`, `b`, and `c'`. If you `word` to be each *line* of output, use a `while` loop with `read`; see [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 1):

If performance isn't critical, the following pipeline which relies on external executables should work just fine :

```
ps -o cmd= | grep -Ewo '[^::space::]*mgr\.prm' | cut -c -15
```

`ps -o cmd=` asks `ps` only to display command-lines (without header), `grep` filters the lines to those which contain a word ending in `mgr.\prm`, `cut` returns only the first 15 characters of that word.

Note that the `grep` `-w`ord-regexp flag isn't POSIX-defined and probably won't work unless you're using GNU `grep`. In that case I recommend either using `grep` with the `-P`CRE regex flavour flag and add a word-`\b`oundary to the end of the pattern, or adding `( |$)` to the end of the pattern.

Comment: Pgrep is not installed by UNIX admins and installation of "pgrep" needs a lot of trivial procedural work:S, but I'll keep it in my mind. Thanks.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN Actually there's not much point to the `pgrep` now that I come to think about it : the following `grep -Eo` will already filter on the relevant lines. I'll just remove it.